# Frontend Joomla Search Plugin - Joomla2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I am in the need of a Joomla Front end search module in Joomla 2.5, which on search , searches in articles, modules, text in any media files, text in pdfs and displays the result all together in a list.

For example: If "phpranav" is the keyword used in any article say "My Nick name", in a module called "Mynickname", in any image named as "phpranav.png", or in any pdf file containing 3 paragraphs with 3 times occurance of "phpranav" keyword, as a metatag in a page, as a heading in a page.. etc...

Then on searching the keyword "phpranav"

I must get the list of all the occurrence from above given description as a data retrieved from search.

Guide me if there is any such plugin already available or I have to create it of my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are [several search extensions on the JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search) that integrate Google etc with Joomla! While we haven't used it for a while the RokAjaxSearch did a good job for one our clients with PDF file. Not sure how it goes with images though.